# 'FBSDKCoreKitImport.h' file not found after update of FBSDK 11.2.0

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

`It returns 'FBSDKCoreKitImport.h' file not found` compile error after update of FBSDK 11.2.0 in XCode. How can I fix this error?[image]

Comment: Have u found the solution ?

Comment: @Nizzam Yes Facebook now relese the next version 11.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@sasquach suggestion didn't work for me.
There is [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1829) relevant GitHub issue on Facebook's SDK repo that you can keep an eye on.

**Update 23-9-21:** Version 11.2.1 seems to fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

temporary solution:

podfile

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 11.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 11.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 11.1.0'
```

and make pod update in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when building in Xcode after having updated FB iOS SDK to version 12.1.0 using `pod update`.

Replace `#import FBSDKLoginKit` with **`#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>`**, then `Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder` and rebuild the project.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `CocoaPods`:

**Delete the `Podfile.lock`** file, and update the podfile with current stable versions of `FBSDKCoreKit` and do `pod install` again.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKCoreKit

Comment: the current stable versions of the FB SDK introduced this issue, so updating does not help